# Using IDbConnection

Tags: c#

Is it possible to extend this interface? I've seen it's possible, but I dont really understand how it works, I'd like to see the documentaiton on that, I saw someone made a class "IDbConnecitonExtension" or something like that and just magically worked.

Comment: Extend how?  Extension methods?  Subclasses?  Unfortunately this is too hard to answer without knowing what you are asking or what "magically works" means.

Comment: This is really vague.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What did this class (or interface?) that "just magically worked" actually do?  There's no magic involved.  And there's no guarantee that what you witnessed is what you want to solve whatever issue you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to extend this interface?

Yes. You extend it just like any other type.

```
public static class IDbConnectionExtensions {
    public static void MyExtension(this IDbConnection connection) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, connection!");
    }
}
```